# Changing elements in pandas series according to other series

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas series with long names like this:

```
0           abrakadabra
1           hokus pokus
2           lumio
3           flippendo   
4           avada kedavra
```

Second with short names:

```
0           abra
1           kra
2           avada
3           hokus          
4           lalala
```

The aim is to check if any element from first list contains element from second list. If so, change elemnt from 1 list to approriate element from second list.
Desirable aoutput:

```
0 abra
1 hokus
2 lumio
3 flippendo
4 avada
```

Below function was created:

```
def common(serie1,serie2):
    for index1,value1 in enumerate(list(serie1)):
         for index2,value2 in enumerate(list(serie2)):
              if value1 in value2:
                  serie2[index2]=value1
              else:
                  serie2[index2]=value2
    return serie2
```

For these 2 short series it works perfectly. However for longer ones function does not hold names from serie2 in cases, when value1 is not in value2 , instead put 0 there. I can't find what is wrong with my function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by joined all values of `s2` by `|` for regex `OR` with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
pat = r'({})'.format('|'.join(s2))
#for exact match
#pat = r'(\b{}\b)'.format('|'.join(s2))
s = s1.str.extract(pat, expand=False).fillna(s1)
print (s)
0         abra
1        hokus
2        lumio
3    flippendo
4        avada
Name: A, dtype: object
```